# Docker container link not setting environment variables

Tags: docker

In two terminal sessions I have the following docker containers running:

`docker run -i --name docker1 centos:centos6 /bin/bash`

`docker run -i --name docker2 centos:centos6 /bin/bash`

`docker ps` yields:

`8c67bb6975f7        centos:centos6      /bin/bash           7 minutes ago      docker1`

`8c67bb6975f7        centos:centos6      /bin/bash           7 minutes ago      docker2`

(Any better way to just run an empty docker container for testing purposes btw?)

When I run `docker run -i --name link --link docker1:docker1 --link docker2:docker2 centos:centos6 /bin/bash` and invoke `env` I get the following result:

```
DOCKER1_NAME=/docker1
HOSTNAME=b8403b72030d
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
SHLVL=1
HOME=/
DOCKER2_NAME=/docker2
```

So as you can see I only get the `NAME` of the containers, and not the port and IP which is what I really want. I feel like there's something I've misunderstood, but I can't tell what it is by looking at the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily a good friend of mine (@tobiasgwaaler) has a better grasp of Docker than I do, and he graciously gave me the answer.

In order for a docker container to share its port and ip it needs to `EXPOSE` the port number. Thus, by simply adding this to my `Dockerfile`:

`EXPOSE <port-number>`

And huzzah, the port and IP are now available in the `env`

```
DOCKER1_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.116:<port-number>
```